# How to ensure number of columns match header definitions fed into Powershell Import-CSV commandlet

Tags: powershell

Here is a shorthand representation of the code

```
Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName -Header Name, Occupation, Department | 
foreach-object{ //perform some string validations}
```

The problem I am having is that I need to throw an error if the CSV file doesn't have exactly 3 values per line. If there are 4 values per line rather than 3, the script won't error out. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName -Header Name, Occupation, Department, Error | 
foreach-object{ 
                if ($_.Error)
                  { Throw "Invalid file format" }
              }
```

Comment: Seems to be working. However, it does not cover the case of too few values (mmissing values)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with this. Not sure if there is a cleaner way to do it though. Maybe a count on the array length since I know how many values to expect?

```
if (($_.Error) -or (!($_.Department))) { Throw "Invalid file format" }
```